# Installing Ubuntu in Acer Aspire v17 nitro for better compatibility with nvidia card

Tags: nvidia, system-installation, graphics

I'm very tired of Nvidia drivers conflicting with windows and BSOD all the time (TDR_video_failure nvlddmkm.sys error). I'd like to know if Ubuntu gives such issues, and, if it will recognize my GPU (I cannot see in the list).

Anyway this is my laptop.

- Intel® Core™ i7-4720HQ processor Quad-core 2.60 GHz
- 17.3" Full HD (1920 x 1080) 16:9 IPS
- NVIDIA® GeForce® GTX 860M with 4 GB Dedicated Memory
- 16 GB, DDR3L SDRAM
- 1 TB HDD, 256 GB SSD

Comment: NVidia has issues with ubuntu also, but most can get it working well once they get the right drivers

Answer (score 0):

Your CPU is from Haswell family so I would recommend following setup:

- Download any Ubuntu flavor 16.04.1 (notice the .1). I recommend this one since it defaults to 4.4.x kernel and older xorg subsystem (no hwe) which in general is more stable for Haswell type machines. For example stock [Ubuntu 16.04.1](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/xenial/ubuntu-16.04-desktop-amd64.iso) .
- Install the OS
- Execute `sudo apt-get update`
- Execute `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade && sudo restart`

Install graphic drivers ppa and latest drivers

```
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get -y install nvidia-381 nvidia-settings
```